# CR2450 Battery SOC vs. Voltage

Tags: voltage, batteries, soc

Just purchased some Maxell CR2450HR batteries off AliExpress for my TPMS sensors. Don't know how long they have been in storage. Is there a way to check how good these batteries are? Measured the open circuit voltage and they all have 3.32V.

Comment: Google: Maxell CR2450HR datasheet. That info should be in the datasheet. https://biz.maxell.com/en/primary_batteries/pdf/CR2450HR_DataSheet_e.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Because primary (i.e. non-rechargeable) coin cell batteries have a flat discharge curve, it's difficult to determine their state of charge from the  open-circuit voltage.

But the cell's internal resistance does rise as it is discharged, so measuring voltage under load can give you a better idea of their remaining capacity.

This battery manufacturer's datasheet [Energizer CR2450 datasheet](https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/cr2450.pdf) has a discharge curve when under load of 7.5K ohms -- giving you a clue what voltage appears at various states of discharge.

The load of a wireless TPMS will consist of periodic, brief high-current pulses (a few milliamps) and long periods of continuous, very low (microamps) drain. Under this condition, the cell capacity may differ significantly from the constant-load curve in the datasheet.

Given the cost and trouble of removing a wheel and dismounting a tire to replace a battery, a better engineering choice is to put the AliExpress batteries in toys, and for the vehicle buy batteries of known authenticity and freshness from an authorized distributor like Digikey or Mouser.